# vb2010 - source code of website using javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

is it possible to get the source code of a website that uses javascript using:

```
    Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.asx.com.au/")

    RichTextBox1.Text = sourceString
```

the above code isn't getting the javascript portion, returns the following as part of the string:

```
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>
```

Comment: You've answered your own question, clearly it's not possible as you can see

Answer (score 0):

Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("SomeWebPage")